# Bluemix DEA->Diego How can I handle the rename of VCAP_APP_PORT AND VCAP_APP_HOST without changing application code?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, diego

I have tested a few apps with enable-diego on Bluemix.  They all broke because of this change.  I could fix most, one I'm still struggling with.  And none of which I actually wanted to make code changes in.

Instead of code changes being required to my apps, can I automate the mapping of the variables at container level (or any other solution)?

Answer (score -1):

Not tried this but maybe you could create a user provided environment variable and set

```
VCAP_APP_PORT = $PORT
```

edit:
You can set user-provided environment variables using the Bluemix UI or using the [cf set-env](http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/set-env.html) command.

Comment: It's actually VCAP_APP_PORT and it won't let me: 

Setting env variable 'VCAP_APP_PORT' to '$PORT' for app xx in org xx / space xx as xx...
FAILED
Server error, status code: 400, error code: 100001, message: The app is invalid: environment_json reserved_key:VCAP_APP_PORT

Comment: Ahh, then I'm afraid you'll have to change your code to use PORT instead.  Note that the PORT variable works in both DEA and Diego.

Comment: Fixed both typos. Shame it didn't work. This is purely conjecture but it might well be that VCAP_APP_PORT is no longer a reserved key once Bluemix transitions to Diego only (and completely away from DEA)

Comment: Or maybe they'll change their mind and not break all my stuff, someone has asked:  https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nsync/pull/16

Comment: That would definitely be preferable :D

Comment: Have you tried modifying the environment variables in a `.profile.d` script?  The `.profile.d` script should run before your application and it shouldn't have any restrictions on what it can do.  You should be able to `export VCAP_APP_PORT=$PORT` there and have it visible to your app.  It won't require any code changes, but you will need to push your app again.

Comment: Nice idea but fails in practice also, at staging: 2016-12-15T09:37:58.25+0000 [STG/0]      ERR mkdir: cannot create directory '/app/.profile.d': File exists.  Odd error actually, it's a file not a directory.

Comment: Hey Daniel, that actually that worked once I renamed it to .profile!  Can you convert to an answer and I'll accept.